# Move each column value from the same group to new column SQL Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have faced an issue when trying to transpose rows to columns.

My table looks like this:

[image]

And the result table should look like this:
[image]

I tried to solve this problem with PIVOT() but then I realized this is not the case.
Can anyone help me with that?

Edit 1: the number of names is not infinite (4 at most).

Edit 2: I've realized I've lost all the rows when there is NULL in name column.

I know I could do it with UNION, but is there more elegant solution to this problem?

[image]

Desired result would then be:
[image]

Comment: is there a set amount of names and are they known? or are there infinite possibilities?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I keep the rows when there is NULL in name column? I appreciate you help!

Consider below

```
select * from (
  select *
  from your_table
  left join unnest(split(name, ', ')) word with offset
)
pivot (min(word) as name for offset + 1 in (1, 2, 3))
```

if applied to sample data in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select 'x1' id, 'yellow' name union all
  select 'x2', 'orange' union all
  select 'x3', 'pink, blue' union all
  select 'x4', 'pink, blue, yellow' union all 
  select 'x5', null union all
  select 'x6', null 
)
```

the output is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Consider below option

```
select * from (
  select *
  from your_table, 
  unnest(split(name, ', ')) word with offset
)
pivot (min(word) as name for offset + 1 in (1, 2, 3))
```

if applied to sample data in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select 'x1' id, 'yellow' name union all
  select 'x2', 'orange' union all
  select 'x3', 'pink, blue' union all
  select 'x4', 'pink, blue, yellow' 
)
```

output is

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: How can I keep the rows when there is NULL in name column? I appreciate you help!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many names you want to split into new columns. With the data that you, shared you can try this query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t1.name,
split(t1.name, ', ')[SAFE_offset(0)] as name_1,
split(t1.name, ', ')[SAFE_offset(1)] as name_2,
split(t1.name, ', ')[SAFE_offset(2)] as name_3
from `dataset.table` as t1
```

This brings the below output:

[image]

I use `SAFE_OFFSET` because if you only use `OFFSET` the id 1,2,3 wouldn’t allow it because they bring nulls.